# fetching from a heroku site

Tags: javascript, heroku, twilio, fetch-api

I've created a web app that allows the user to input their phone number and click enter to receive a call from a number that i bought from twilio. It does this by fetching a phone number from my localhost db.I now have the web app on a heroku server. But when i click call i get these errors.

"Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

"Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Type error"

it was working fine when i was fetching it from local host but now I'm having issues. can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thank you

js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", function(req, resp){
resp.sendFile(__dirname+"/input.html");
});



app.get("/:data", function(req, resp){

var accountSid = 'accountsid'
var authToken = 'tokensid'

var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.create({
url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
to: req.params.data,
from: '3738373839',

});
```

html file

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" id="inputNum" />
<button id="submitNum">Enter</button>

<script>



submitNum.addEventListener("click", function(){

var inputNum = document.getElementById("inputNum");
var submitNum = document.getElementById("submitNum");

var phoneNumber = inputNum.value;

fetch("https://******.herokuapp.com" 
+ phoneNumber).then((resp)=>{
console.log(resp);
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any of the code (though make sure not to post the full server address). An app on heroku won't have access to your local database, so you'll need to use hosted version of whatever you have locally (mongo/postgres/etc)

Comment: Have you set up a non-local db to fetch from? When the app is hosted on a non-local host, it can't talk to your local services.

Comment: I've added the code above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these aren't typos, `"http://https://******.herokuapp.com"` isn't a valid server (note the `http` twice). I'd suggest changing that to `"/" + phoneNumber` so it uses the current host of the site (localhost or heroku) wherever it's run.

Separately, as a matter of style, you should put your `twilio` client outside your GET function so it's only created once, not every time someone calls the endpoint.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. the link is just "https://********.herokuapp.com"

Comment: do you have a line number where you're getting the error? is it on the fetch line? Also, you don't have a `catch`, so whatever error that's being returned from the promise is getting dropped. `console.log`ing it would be useful.

Comment: I think this might be it, the URL needs the `/` in it between the domain and the `phoneNumber`. Ensure you've updated that too @RAY.